# Error message not displayed in php form

Tags: php, forms

If user leaves anything blank, my error messages do not display. It simply takes me to my action page where the input is blank. Why don't my errors display? Thanks.

```
<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form name="form2" method="post" action="favorites.php"> 
Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
<br><br>
Favorite Season:
<input type="radio" name="season" value="winter">Winter
<input type="radio" name="season" value="spring">Spring
<input type="radio" name="season" value="summer" checked>Summer
<input type="radio" name="season" value="fall">Fall
<span class="error">* <?php echo $seasonErr;?></span>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

Your name is: <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your favorite season is: <?php echo $_POST["season"]; ?><br>
<?php
$nameErr =  $seasonErr = "";
$name =  $season  = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
$nameErr = "Name is required";
} else {
$name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["season"])) {
$seasonErr = "Season is required";
} else {
$season = test_input($_POST["season"]);
}
}
function test_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}
?>
```

Comment: You should be seeing undefined index/variables notices here. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason being is, that you have your PHP below your form. Place it above your HTML form.

Sidenote: This answers the question and does not cover the fact that you should be getting undefined index notices on initial page load, depending on how your server's error reporting level is setup.

```
<?php
$nameErr =  $seasonErr = "";
$name =  $season  = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
$nameErr = "Name is required";
} else {
$name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["season"])) {
$seasonErr = "Season is required";
} else {
$season = test_input($_POST["season"]);
}
}
function test_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}
?>

<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form name="form2" method="post" action="favorites.php"> 
Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
<br><br>
Favorite Season:
<input type="radio" name="season" value="winter">Winter
<input type="radio" name="season" value="spring">Spring
<input type="radio" name="season" value="summer" checked>Summer
<input type="radio" name="season" value="fall">Fall
<span class="error">* <?php echo $seasonErr;?></span>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

Your name is: <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your favorite season is: <?php echo $_POST["season"]; ?><br>
```

---

- So, it's best to check if anything is set/not empty.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: @Anant Only when I know 100% ;-) if I have at least 0.01% doubt, I stand to be wrong *lol*

Comment: yes i knew it, but i always see you are correct and elaborative. I learn lot of new things from you